# CollectionFS images not fully loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, meteor

I've just come across a werid problem, It seems my images are sometimes only loading slightly. Sometimes when I refresh the page manually they load fully but a lot of the time this happens - http://i.gyazo.com/a7050e430c79aa31ba557fc8271f1502.png

Not really sure why this is happening, I'm using collectionFS with cfs-ejson-file and cfs-s3 to store the images.

Here some example code ( main profile image )

Template code -

```
<div class="profile-avatar" style="height: 261px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
     {{#if avatar }}
       {{#if avatarReady }}
         <img width="261px" height="261px" src="{{avatar.url}}" class="profile-avatar-img thumbnail" alt="Profile Image">
        {{else}}
            <div class="activity-spinner">
                {{>spinner}}
            </div>
       {{/if}}
      {{else}}
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x100%/text:No Profile Photo">
     {{/if}}  
</div> <!-- /.profile-avatar -->
```

Js code -

```
Template.profileLeft.helpers({
    avatar: function(){
        if(this.profile && this.profile.images)
            return Images.findOne(this.profile.images[0]._id);
    },
    avatarReady: function(){
        if(this.profile && this.profile.images){
            var image = Images.findOne(this.profile.images[0]._id);
            return image && image.isUploaded && image.hasStored("images");
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar problem to what you described. When I would upload an image and immediately display it, initially only a portion of it shows. I'll go into what I found and hopefully it helps.

I found that this was only happening when I would use a custom transformWrite: function in CollectionFS. What I believe is happening is there is a race condition causing the image.isUploaded() and image.hasStored() functions to return *true* before GraphicsMagick has finished writing the entire file. The partially processed image is then requested and cached by the web server. Like you said, sometimes when you refresh, the image will be then fully loaded.

As an example:

Your avatar URL that shows a partially processed image:
http://yourdomain.com/cfs/files/images/Bun5qheJDeaZDp5Mf/DSC_5498.JPG?&store=images

Add a fake query param to get around the cache, and the full image should be displayed:
http://yourdomain.com/cfs/files/images/Bun5qheJDeaZDp5Mf/DSC_5498.JPG?&store=images**&bust=cache**

What I ended up doing was setting an additional value on the model that was triggered whenever the image was finished processing. Below is an example of a gm function to process an image. Once the function is finished, another function is called "finishedProcessing" that sets the value on the model.

Sample Code:

```
gm(readStream, fileObj.name())
            .resize(1000).quality(75)
            .stream(function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                if (err) {
                    return err;
                }
                stdout.pipe(writeStream);

                // Update value when processing is finished
                stdout.on('end', function(){
                  finishedProcessing(fileObj._id);
                }); 
            });
```

You can then grab the value of image.finishedProcessing before displaying the image:

```
avatarReady: function(){
        if(this.profile && this.profile.images){
            var image = Images.findOne(this.profile.images[0]._id);
            return image && image.isUploaded() && image.hasStored("images") && image.finishedProcessing;
        }
    }
```

This seemed to work pretty well for me. Even if you're not using GraphicsMagick, there may be a similar condition that's happening when the file is being processed or saved.

Also, on a side note, I believe you need to call "image.isUploaded()" instead of "image.isUploaded" in your helper function to get the proper returned value.

UPDATE: On another another side note, I found that after refactoring if you do not have your collection settings set to Allow Update, then only the first chunk of the image will be saved and it can also cause the issue you are seeing.

```
Images.allow({
    update: function(userId, file, fields, modifier) {

        // This is to check whether or not CollectionFS is trying
        // to update the Image
        var validCFSUpdate = _.intersection(fields, ['chunkSize', 'chunkCount', 'chunkSize']).length > 0

        // Only allow logged in users and CollectionFS to update the Image
        return userId && validCFSUpdate;
    }
});
```